# Katalon Studio Web Recorder seeing current step

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I have recorded a test case via Katalon Studio -> Web Recorder and now I'm running it to check if everything goes as expected (still in Web Recorder UI).

Something goes wrong, can I see the current step Katalon tries to execute?

Comment: It is not very clear what are you asking. What happens when you try to run the recorded test case?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem about object's xpath. When you add objects to object repository with recorder , sometimes they are not working because it is coming as a default marked tag and class. You should select xpath and you can use easily.